# Tinymce4 Remove background-color from text with colorpicker

Tags: tinymce-4

When the user marks a text, he can define a backgroundcolor with the colorpicker (textcolor.plugin).
Once saved he can change the background-color but not get rid of it.
`background-color:white` is no solution as the bodycolor can be RGB or even a picture.
How is the colorpicker to configure to remove the style-tag or at least insert a `background-color:none`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution changing the plugin (textcolor). If there is a better way please be free to post it.

I added additional colors to the colorpicker. The Color #FFFFFe (near White) i marked as NO COLOR and changed the plugin as shown.

```
function onPanelClick(e) {
    var buttonCtrl = this.parent(), value;

    if ((value = e.target.getAttribute('data-mce-color'))) {
        buttonCtrl.hidePanel();
        value = '#' + value;
        buttonCtrl.color(value);
        if (value == '#FFFFFe') {  //Changing the value to -1 causes deletion :-)
            value = -1;
        }
        editor.execCommand(buttonCtrl.settings.selectcmd, false, value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Good hint, but when I have set background color of text and want to remove background color only litle selected part, this will not work. Have you any idea about this? Please, reply asap.

Comment: I see an know that Problem. But maybe you can expand the selectin whith something like: outer =  tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.getNode().outerHTML; but i have no solution present

Comment: That `outer` you pointed is good for me, I will try something, when it will works, I will reply.

Answer (score 0):

Researched a bit more since the given answer did not work in my version 4.5.0 of tinymce.

The textcolor plugin uses 'editor.formatter.remove(...)' to remove text color or background color upon selecting 'x' in the last option of the color palette for 'no color'.
While that function is used elsewhere successfully in tinymce (e.g. when removing italics from text), in the context of the textcolor plugin it does not remove color formatting.

**Solution:**

Replace the following in the textcolor's plugin.js:

> editor.formatter.remove(format, {value: null}, null, true);

with:

> editor.dom.removeAllAttribs(editor.selection.getNode());

...or in the minified version plugin.min.js:

> a.formatter.remove(b,{value:null},null,!0),

with:

> a.dom.removeAllAttribs(a.selection.getNode()),

...and things start working as intended.